# Is there a Natural Language Match function like the one in MySQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, nlp

I was seeing the Natural Language match Function in MySQL which finds any matching strings on a query and returns the match score for any matching results. Is there a similar function in PostgreSQL?

I am aware of the TSQuery function and was looking for something more similar to the said MySQL function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly MySQL's natural language match function does, but it makes me think of the following PostgreSQL features:

- `soundex`, `metaphone` and `dmetaphone` from the [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) extension (`soundex` is somewhat old-fashioned, the others more state of the art)
- the similarity operator `%` from the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) extension

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is the difference between Similarity and Strict_Word_Similarity?

Comment: `similarity` measures the similarity between the first argument and the complete second argument, while `strict_word_similarity` measures the similarity between the first argument and the most similar word in the second argument (words are separated by non-letters here).